# Plot a mean value for many groups - how to fix grouping and labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am wondering if it is possible to plot a line which reflect the mean of specific rows in df. I have a set of lipids and I would like to highlight the mean value of pH = 7 from column rep for WT/SHC. I almost managed to do it, the problem is that the line should be shorter and show the mean of particular lipids. And as well in the legend dots should represent only the type of lipids and line should present mean of standard.

Here is my plot: 
[image]

This is a data I am using:

```
test_cl <- structure(list(type = c("WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "SHC", 
"SHC", "SHC", "SHC", "SHC"), lipids = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("DIP", 
"mDIP", "CL [66:0]", "CL [70:2]", "CL [70:4]", "CL [72:4]", "CL [74:2]", 
"PC [32:1]", "PC [32:2]", "PC [34:1]", "PC [34:2]", "PC [34:3]", 
"PC [34:4]", "PC [36:2]", "PC [36:3]", "PC [36:4]", "PE [32:1]", 
"PE [34:1]", "PE [34:2]", "PE [36:1]", "PE [36:2]", "PE [36:3]", 
"PG [32:1]", "PG [34:1]", "PG [34:2]", "PG [36:2]", "PG [36:3]"
), class = "factor"), rep = c("early1", "early1", "early1", "early1", 
"early1", "early1", "early1", "early1", "early1", "early1", "early2", 
"early2", "early2", "early2", "early2", "early2", "early2", "early2", 
"early2", "early2", "early3", "early3", "early3", "early3", "early3", 
"early3", "early3", "early3", "early3", "early3", "mid1", "mid1", 
"mid1", "mid1", "mid1", "mid1", "mid1", "mid1", "mid1", "mid1", 
"mid2", "mid2", "mid2", "mid2", "mid2", "mid2", "mid2", "mid2", 
"mid2", "mid2", "mid3", "mid3", "mid3", "mid3", "mid3", "mid3", 
"mid3", "mid3", "mid3", "mid3", "late1", "late1", "late1", "late1", 
"late1", "late1", "late1", "late1", "late1", "late1", "late2", 
"late2", "late2", "late2", "late2", "late2", "late2", "late2", 
"late2", "late2", "late3", "late3", "late3", "late3", "late3", 
"late3", "late3", "late3", "late3", "late3", "stat1", "stat1", 
"stat1", "stat1", "stat1", "stat1", "stat1", "stat1", "stat1", 
"stat1", "stat2", "stat2", "stat2", "stat2", "stat2", "stat2", 
"stat2", "stat2", "stat2", "stat2", "stat3", "stat3", "stat3", 
"stat3", "stat3", "stat3", "stat3", "stat3", "stat3", "stat3", 
"pH 5.5 1", "pH 5.5 1", "pH 5.5 1", "pH 5.5 1", "pH 5.5 1", "pH 5.5 1", 
"pH 5.5 1", "pH 5.5 1", "pH 5.5 1", "pH 5.5 1", "pH 5.5 2", "pH 5.5 2", 
"pH 5.5 2", "pH 5.5 2", "pH 5.5 2", "pH 5.5 2", "pH 5.5 2", "pH 5.5 2", 
"pH 5.5 2", "pH 5.5 2", "pH 5.5 3", "pH 5.5 3", "pH 5.5 3", "pH 5.5 3", 
"pH 5.5 3", "pH 5.5 3", "pH 5.5 3", "pH 5.5 3", "pH 5.5 3", "pH 5.5 3", 
"pH 6 1", "pH 6 1", "pH 6 1", "pH 6 1", "pH 6 1", "pH 6 1", "pH 6 1", 
"pH 6 1", "pH 6 1", "pH 6 1", "pH 6 2", "pH 6 2", "pH 6 2", "pH 6 2", 
"pH 6 2", "pH 6 2", "pH 6 2", "pH 6 2", "pH 6 2", "pH 6 2", "pH 6 3", 
"pH 6 3", "pH 6 3", "pH 6 3", "pH 6 3", "pH 6 3", "pH 6 3", "pH 6 3", 
"pH 6 3", "pH 6 3", "pH 7 1", "pH 7 1", "pH 7 1", "pH 7 1", "pH 7 1", 
"pH 7 1", "pH 7 1", "pH 7 1", "pH 7 1", "pH 7 1", "pH 7 2", "pH 7 2", 
"pH 7 2", "pH 7 2", "pH 7 2", "pH 7 2", "pH 7 2", "pH 7 2", "pH 7 2", 
"pH 7 2", "pH 7 3", "pH 7 3", "pH 7 3", "pH 7 3", "pH 7 3", "pH 7 3", 
"pH 7 3", "pH 7 3", "pH 7 3", "pH 7 3", "pH 7.5 1", "pH 7.5 1", 
"pH 7.5 1", "pH 7.5 1", "pH 7.5 1", "pH 7.5 1", "pH 7.5 1", "pH 7.5 1", 
"pH 7.5 1", "pH 7.5 1", "pH 7.5 2", "pH 7.5 2", "pH 7.5 2", "pH 7.5 2", 
"pH 7.5 2", "pH 7.5 2", "pH 7.5 2", "pH 7.5 2", "pH 7.5 2", "pH 7.5 2", 
"pH 7.5 3", "pH 7.5 3", "pH 7.5 3", "pH 7.5 3", "pH 7.5 3", "pH 7.5 3", 
"pH 7.5 3", "pH 7.5 3", "pH 7.5 3", "pH 7.5 3", "13C 1", "13C 1", 
"13C 1", "13C 1", "13C 1", "13C 1", "13C 1", "13C 1", "13C 1", 
"13C 1", "13C 2", "13C 2", "13C 2", "13C 2", "13C 2", "13C 2", 
"13C 2", "13C 2", "13C 2", "13C 2", "13C 3", "13C 3", "13C 3", 
"13C 3", "13C 3", "13C 3", "13C 3", "13C 3", "13C 3", "13C 3", 
"20C 1", "20C 1", "20C 1", "20C 1", "20C 1", "20C 1", "20C 1", 
"20C 1", "20C 1", "20C 1", "20C 2", "20C 2", "20C 2", "20C 2", 
"20C 2", "20C 2", "20C 2", "20C 2", "20C 2", "20C 2", "20C 3", 
"20C 3", "20C 3", "20C 3", "20C 3", "20C 3", "20C 3", "20C 3", 
"20C 3", "20C 3", "30C 1", "30C 1", "30C 1", "30C 1", "30C 1", 
"30C 1", "30C 1", "30C 1", "30C 1", "30C 1", "30C 2", "30C 2", 
"30C 2", "30C 2", "30C 2", "30C 2", "30C 2", "30C 2", "30C 2", 
"30C 2", "30C 3", "30C 3", "30C 3", "30C 3", "30C 3", "30C 3", 
"30C 3", "30C 3", "30C 3", "30C 3", "NaCl 0.05 1", "NaCl 0.05 1", 
"NaCl 0.05 1", "NaCl 0.05 1", "NaCl 0.05 1", "NaCl 0.05 1", "NaCl 0.05 1", 
"NaCl 0.05 1", "NaCl 0.05 1", "NaCl 0.05 1", "NaCl 0.05 2", "NaCl 0.05 2", 
"NaCl 0.05 2", "NaCl 0.05 2", "NaCl 0.05 2", "NaCl 0.05 2", "NaCl 0.05 2", 
"NaCl 0.05 2", "NaCl 0.05 2", "NaCl 0.05 2", "NaCl 0.05 3", "NaCl 0.05 3", 
"NaCl 0.05 3", "NaCl 0.05 3", "NaCl 0.05 3", "NaCl 0.05 3", "NaCl 0.05 3", 
"NaCl 0.05 3", "NaCl 0.05 3", "NaCl 0.05 3", "NaCl 0.1 1", "NaCl 0.1 1", 
"NaCl 0.1 1", "NaCl 0.1 1", "NaCl 0.1 1", "NaCl 0.1 1", "NaCl 0.1 1", 
"NaCl 0.1 1", "NaCl 0.1 1", "NaCl 0.1 1", "NaCl 0.1 2", "NaCl 0.1 2", 
"NaCl 0.1 2", "NaCl 0.1 2", "NaCl 0.1 2", "NaCl 0.1 2", "NaCl 0.1 2", 
"NaCl 0.1 2", "NaCl 0.1 2", "NaCl 0.1 2", "NaCl 0.1 3", "NaCl 0.1 3", 
"NaCl 0.1 3", "NaCl 0.1 3", "NaCl 0.1 3", "NaCl 0.1 3", "NaCl 0.1 3", 
"NaCl 0.1 3", "NaCl 0.1 3", "NaCl 0.1 3", "MetOH 0.1 1", "MetOH 0.1 1", 
"MetOH 0.1 1", "MetOH 0.1 1", "MetOH 0.1 1", "MetOH 0.1 1", "MetOH 0.1 1", 
"MetOH 0.1 1", "MetOH 0.1 1", "MetOH 0.1 1", "MetOH 0.1 2", "MetOH 0.1 2", 
"MetOH 0.1 2", "MetOH 0.1 2", "MetOH 0.1 2", "MetOH 0.1 2", "MetOH 0.1 2", 
"MetOH 0.1 2", "MetOH 0.1 2", "MetOH 0.1 2", "MetOH 0.1 3", "MetOH 0.1 3", 
"MetOH 0.1 3", "MetOH 0.1 3", "MetOH 0.1 3", "MetOH 0.1 3", "MetOH 0.1 3", 
"MetOH 0.1 3", "MetOH 0.1 3", "MetOH 0.1 3", "MetOH 1 1", "MetOH 1 1", 
"MetOH 1 1", "MetOH 1 1", "MetOH 1 1", "MetOH 1 1", "MetOH 1 1", 
"MetOH 1 1", "MetOH 1 1", "MetOH 1 1", "MetOH 1 2", "MetOH 1 2", 
"MetOH 1 2", "MetOH 1 2", "MetOH 1 2", "MetOH 1 2", "MetOH 1 2", 
"MetOH 1 2", "MetOH 1 2", "MetOH 1 2", "MetOH 1 3", "MetOH 1 3", 
"MetOH 1 3", "MetOH 1 3", "MetOH 1 3", "MetOH 1 3", "MetOH 1 3", 
"MetOH 1 3", "MetOH 1 3", "MetOH 1 3"), num = c(0.009523686, 
0.043189398, 0.420979104, 0.246671197, 3.451885409, 0.015840778, 
0.066796591, 0.711819877, 0.266602215, 3.454463141, 0.007613802, 
0.046278008, 0.392051405, 0.25502036, 3.159879284, 0.023401093, 
0.083028102, 0.496309773, 0.312034391, 2.537644531, 0.011478203, 
0.054305349, 0.464326108, 0.307066853, 3.6602462, 0.022539611, 
0.088932716, 0.561775816, 0.306176596, 2.67694279, 0.010537286, 
0.04003825, 0.433807129, 0.265128974, 3.793074386, 0.033332936, 
0.125527261, 0.665685118, 0.433383167, 3.079080661, 0.007334728, 
0.050505078, 0.380642914, 0.297303594, 3.223705784, 0.028779332, 
0.133574985, 0.627769179, 0.44754806, 2.958721891, 0.006611086, 
0.030062788, 0.368471191, 0.196684816, 3.41357708, 0.029912455, 
0.123199878, 0.725256378, 0.429472199, 3.320616551, 0.01118598, 
0.079753642, 0.42517786, 0.475724091, 3.136961558, 0.02541216, 
0.092255666, 0.700284371, 0.310205814, 3.021941072, 0.011543492, 
0.074750731, 0.436643281, 0.41869653, 3.16178206, 0.016723165, 
0.107711653, 0.478617926, 0.327257309, 2.187418617, 0.014526945, 
0.083030295, 0.421018391, 0.453286503, 3.034308389, 0.013312235, 
0.094337923, 0.604186915, 0.319925114, 2.710050374, 0.018963327, 
0.134905674, 0.324578481, 0.675510653, 2.075633975, 0.048011844, 
0.173339125, 0.671572835, 0.410361322, 1.686563816, 0.020817582, 
0.138788879, 0.322903267, 0.686792019, 2.160872891, 0.045915999, 
0.186073834, 0.623858447, 0.427157351, 1.630243088, 0.02334196, 
0.141525911, 0.326552113, 0.705404966, 2.160032852, 0.056147482, 
0.177409855, 0.776909273, 0.40933411, 1.976242185, 0.004633127, 
0.148588149, 0.486888237, 0.692898358, 2.642813555, 0.04514786, 
0.293542177, 0.628124318, 0.92269088, 2.427045621, 0.009330446, 
0.157310452, 0.389913986, 0.69311545, 2.373673687, 0.032803203, 
0.293311922, 0.512466096, 0.94176273, 1.966838355, 0.016920389, 
0.153930147, 0.407931604, 0.66933255, 2.43192777, 0.045960156, 
0.270842741, 0.599652483, 0.820429999, 2.189575381, 0.017778907, 
0.118991857, 0.472321709, 0.613337385, 3.115415618, 0.028992327, 
0.229761789, 0.492154055, 0.842800722, 2.242849613, 0.023182626, 
0.119038523, 0.582892594, 0.597699301, 3.779952255, 0.03861396, 
0.233904848, 0.569834529, 0.811853695, 2.573955654, 0.023031255, 
0.119210287, 0.572679168, 0.611935847, 3.685191127, 0.04358965, 
0.334758071, 0.736448747, 1.231148933, 3.280921801, 0.007902522, 
0.098307685, 0.616613495, 0.437905544, 4.150185864, 0.01725995, 
0.154284081, 0.709570519, 0.426857487, 2.970822428, 0.005021786, 
0.092351365, 0.331772789, 0.476369777, 2.082020853, 0.018188753, 
0.136003722, 0.569063573, 0.454751015, 2.296572566, 0.006793196, 
0.090945613, 0.410991263, 0.449364368, 2.536806135, 0.032270599, 
0.150618359, 0.759625702, 0.447729593, 3.01282956, 0.007153489, 
0.10780106, 0.574597942, 0.476387687, 2.915254622, 0.06383629, 
0.264258274, 0.548375265, 0.711833684, 2.155158445, 0.017068877, 
0.118768278, 0.599951373, 0.477224531, 3.186731876, 0.026518865, 
0.26922641, 0.682501252, 0.753471226, 2.681314829, 0.014697648, 
0.11854954, 0.537912378, 0.532150804, 2.962629872, 0.02748779, 
0.262262926, 0.701643907, 0.730112753, 2.943014213, 0.001144995, 
0.108661125, 0.41072655, 0.401729495, 3.349649409, 0.004814308, 
0.138971717, 0.351954191, 0.397538279, 1.810974482, 0.000854878, 
0.076091557, 0.317566463, 0.265579988, 2.697381593, 0.006671769, 
0.143615213, 0.375693318, 0.432116471, 1.964832118, 0.001387258, 
0.089433716, 0.347318908, 0.310210558, 2.831744905, 0.011747384, 
0.161909067, 0.483097774, 0.434049624, 2.495174754, 0.002421467, 
0.052017808, 0.32257307, 0.321733033, 2.913409569, 0.006364221, 
0.108896499, 0.400344628, 0.45083928, 2.612358054, 0.002088531, 
0.062392598, 0.345417305, 0.376732525, 3.148227718, 0.007314019, 
0.115997721, 0.382326299, 0.456267995, 2.548147974, 0.002197505, 
0.056822917, 0.329202368, 0.327668171, 3.060426171, 0.004130378, 
0.095727468, 0.256862326, 0.449779773, 1.707117768, 0.009523686, 
0.043189398, 0.420979104, 0.246671197, 3.451885409, 0.015840778, 
0.066796591, 0.711819877, 0.266602215, 3.454463141, 0.007613802, 
0.046278008, 0.392051405, 0.25502036, 3.159879284, 0.023401093, 
0.083028102, 0.496309773, 0.312034391, 2.537644531, 0.011478203, 
0.054305349, 0.464326108, 0.307066853, 3.6602462, 0.022539611, 
0.088932716, 0.561775816, 0.306176596, 2.67694279, 0.013238195, 
0.116731516, 0.513870128, 0.714466207, 4.13215759, 0.017830501, 
0.256775249, 0.566607585, 0.768765952, 2.099092988, 0.005996389, 
0.131612407, 0.391253262, 0.807713856, 3.192910963, 0.010803128, 
0.267512693, 0.49323859, 0.809247089, 1.75861532, 0.007420278, 
0.130344538, 0.370661217, 0.821807125, 3.157958777, 0.027113392, 
0.260864254, 0.697775301, 0.828808324, 2.503637112, 0.008109203, 
0.126053618, 0.424421426, 0.736527329, 3.138838862, 0.030241241, 
0.401973349, 0.749110588, 0.982360012, 1.95767926, 0.008821784, 
0.120380007, 0.445323375, 0.698091901, 3.2819844, 0.035769782, 
0.383012382, 0.745898962, 0.940316819, 2.021141233, 0.009709852, 
0.119421859, 0.460181194, 0.662124848, 3.418103048, 0.035575143, 
0.408529835, 0.817553592, 0.979699253, 2.191139604, 0.014092665, 
0.088921329, 0.400118909, 0.533636754, 3.211855928, 0.023826824, 
0.21030273, 0.450340544, 0.813043891, 2.450184786, 0.002871928, 
0.093172622, 0.313849684, 0.56060567, 2.618043655, 0.022990767, 
0.190713274, 0.542822273, 0.771433207, 2.977290039, 0.018301729, 
0.086026637, 0.440453336, 0.560300392, 3.600196218, 0.026158589, 
0.176415047, 0.514817064, 0.713635504, 2.745529632, 0.019531106, 
0.093643383, 0.419362398, 0.54614676, 3.085470045, 0.028815782, 
0.187065712, 0.520767972, 0.645079007, 2.374529212, 0.021278598, 
0.099665663, 0.412005508, 0.60694041, 3.16902752, 0.041771475, 
0.171868691, 0.517726713, 0.580779114, 2.261748875, 0.01654279, 
0.104298166, 0.362437548, 0.602720163, 2.799936307, 0.033620427, 
0.203394035, 0.589582994, 0.690476977, 2.759532167), groups = c("Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", 
"Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Growth stage", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", 
"Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Ph", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", 
"Temperature", "Temperature", "Temperature", "NaCl", "NaCl", 
"NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", 
"NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", 
"NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", 
"NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", 
"NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", 
"NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", 
"NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", "NaCl", 
"NaCl", "NaCl", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", 
"MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", 
"MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", 
"MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", 
"MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", 
"MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", 
"MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", 
"MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", 
"MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH", "MetOH")), row.names = c(NA, 
-450L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "rep", "num", "groups"))
```

And the code I have so far:

```
ph7 <- test_cl
ph7$rep<-sub("X","",ph7$rep)
ph7$rep<-sub("\\d$","",ph7$rep)
ph7$rep<-sub("\\.$","",ph7$rep)
ph7 <- ph7 %>% group_by(type, lipids, groups, rep)%>% summarise_all( funs(mean(.)))

ggplot(test_cl, aes(x = factor(lipids), y= num, col = type)) + 
  geom_point(size = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.3))+
  geom_hline(data = filter(ph7, grepl('pH 7 ', rep)),aes(yintercept = num ,col = type)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = '') +
  scale_color_discrete(name = 'standard') +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         axis.text.x=element_text(angle=0,hjust=1),
         text = element_text(size=5)
        ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("WT" = "grey50", "SHC" = "tomato") ) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, 0.9))
```

I was trying to use stat_summary but there I do not know how to change dot to short line (without connections) and how to fix the legend there.

```
ph7 <- test_cl
ph7$rep<-sub("X","",ph7$rep)
ph7$rep<-sub("\\d$","",ph7$rep)
ph7$rep<-sub("\\.$","",ph7$rep)
ph7 <- ph7 %>% group_by(type, lipids, groups, rep)%>% summarise_all( funs(mean(.)))

ggplot(test_cl, aes(x = factor(lipids), y= num, col = type)) + 
  geom_point(size = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.3))+
  #geom_hline(data = filter(ph7, grepl('pH 7 ', rep)),aes(yintercept = num ,col = type)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = '') +
  scale_color_discrete(name = 'standard') +
  #geom_point(data = ph7,aes(col = type), size= 0.7, position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  stat_summary(data = filter(ph7,grepl('pH 7 ', rep)), fun.y=mean, geom="point", lwd=2, aes(group=factor(type)), show.legend= TRUE,position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         axis.text.x=element_text(angle=0,hjust=1),
         text = element_text(size=5)
        ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("WT" = "grey50", "SHC" = "tomato") ) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, 0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Is the first plot what you want? Is the second plot what you have currently?

Comment: I want the second plot but instead of the dot I would like to have a short line (as in the first plot but not through whole hight of the plot). I want to mark the mean value of ph 7 for each CL. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_segment` like this:

Define starting and ending `x` and starting and ending `y` positions

```
positions <- data.frame(x1=c(0.8),
                       x2=c(1.0),
                       y1=filter(ph7, grepl('pH 7 ', rep))$num[1],
                       y2=filter(ph7, grepl('pH 7 ', rep))$num[1],
                       label=filter(ph7, grepl('pH 7 ', rep))$type[1])
```

Then add `geom_segment` in-line

```
ggplot(test_cl, aes(x = factor(lipids), y= num, col = type)) + 
   geom_point(size = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.3))+
geom_segment(aes(x=x1,y=y1,xend=x2,yend=y2,colour=label),lwd=1,data=positions)
```

I didn't add all your values because you'll need to format `filter(ph7, grepl('pH 7 ', rep))` appropriately, and the starting and ending positions of each line.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail how to do it? I mean, do I have to add a df "position" for each CL type separately?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately...`x1=c(0.8,1,1.8,2,2.8,3,3.8,4,4.8,5)`... `x2=c(1,1.2,2,2.2,3,3.2,4,4.2,5.5.2)`... For `y1` and `y2` you can use something like `filter(ph7, grepl('pH 7 ', rep))$num[1]` but you'll need to match up each value with their respective sample (that is, re-order `$num`). The same is true for `label`.

Comment: cool, thanks! what about a legend? Would it be possible to add the segment to legend and explain it is a mean value?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible...but you should definitely post as a separate question. Something like `is it possible to merge legends for geom_point and geom_segment?` Make a toy plot with very simple data to receive the most help.